# iOS App Not Theme-ing Properly with the UINavigationBar, Background and UITabBar with Segues and Tab Bars

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, nsuserdefaults, segue

This is likely to be a long question because I've done some extensive testing and I'm quite stuck.

The App is like this:

`Two Tabs` in a `Tab Bar Controller`; both tabs are `Table View Controllers`. In `Tab Bar one`, we have the `Timeline`. In `Tab Bar two`, we have the `Settings`. If the user clicks on the `cell` labeled `Themes` in the `Settings Table View`, they're taken to a `UICollectionView` (embedded in a `UIViewController` with a custom `UICollectionViewCell`) called `Themes` via a `Push Segue`.

The themes and labels of the cells are loaded in via `NSArrays`. That works.

The issue I'm having is when selecting a cell to change the theme, I'm getting some strange behaviour.

If the user selects a theme, the `background` of the view changes, the `tab bar` changes, but the `navigation bar` does not.

Scenario 1 (After selecting a theme):

If I go back to the `Settings Table View`, the `navigation bar` is still not correct (still the old navigational bar). From here, if I go to the `Timeline tab`, the `navigation bar` changes to the appropriate theme. If I go back to the `Settings Table View` and go to the `Theme Collections`, the `navigation bar` is the same navigation bar from the `App Settings`, but not the correct `navigation bar` (because I'm using a transparent `navigation bar` in the `Themes Collection`).

Scenario 2:

If I've selected a theme in the `Themes Collection` and DON'T go back to the `Settings` but instead go straight to the `Timeline`, the `Navigation Bar` is correct in the `Timeline` and if I go back to the second tab (which is in the `Themes Collection View`), the `navigation bar` uses the appropriate `Transparent` `navigation bar` for the `Themes Collection View`.

In both scenarios, although I'm getting very different behaviour, the first problem is: **When I select a theme, the background changes with the tab bar, but the `Nav bar` does not**.

The second problem is I don't quite understand what is actually happening with the `viewWillAppears`, `viewDidLoads`, etc.

So I set out some serious logging.

First, here's the code in the `Themes Collection`.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ThemeCell *themeCell = (ThemeCell *)[self.cView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.selectedTheme = themeCell.cellLabel.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.selectedTheme forKey:@"Theme"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self changeAppThemes];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear in Theme Collection");
    NSLog(@"The value of the selectedTheme in the viewWillAppear of the Theme Collection is: %@", self.selectedTheme);
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        self.selectedTheme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Theme"];

    if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Blur"])
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepink.png"]];

        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentNav.png"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SolidPurple.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];        
    }
    else if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Default"])
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Newiphonebackground.png"]];
        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentNav.png"];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentTab.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Twirl"])
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ReddishBlack.png"]];
        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentNav.png"];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentTab.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
    }
    else 
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Newiphonebackground.png"]];
        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplynav.png"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentTab.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
    }
}

- (void)changeAppThemes
{
    NSLog(@"ChangeAppThemes in Theme Collection");
    NSLog(@"The value of the selectedTheme in the changeAppThemes of the ThemeCollection is: %@", self.selectedTheme);

    self.selectedTheme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Theme"];

// Same code that's viewWillAppear with the setting of the themes based on self.selectedTheme
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// loading arrays
}
```

In the `App Settings,` I have the code for the themes in the `viewWillAppear` only.

In the `Timeline`, I have the code for the themes in the `viewWillAppear` only.

Here are the extensive NSLogs from all three controllers:

```
**App loads into Timeline:**

viewDidLoad of the timeline
selectedTheme in viewDidLoad = null

viewWillAppear of the Timeline
selectedTheme in viewWillAppear = null

**Click On App Settings Tab:**

viewDidLoad of the App Settings
selecteTheme in viewDidLoad = null

viewWillAppear of the App Settings
selectedTheme in the viewWillAppear = null

**Segue into Theme Collections by clicking on Themes Cell**

viewDidLoad of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the viewDidLoad = null

viewWillAppear of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the viewWillAppear = null

changeAppThemes of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the changeApptThemes = null; 

**Peacock Theme Selected;**

changeAppThemes of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the changeAppThemes = Peacock
// Navigation Bar does not change at this point

**Back to the App Settings Table View:**

viewWillAppear in the App Settings
selectedTheme in the AppSettings = null

**Segue to Themes Again**

viewDidLoad of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the viewDidLoad = null

viewWillAppear of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the viewWillAppear = null

changeAppThemes of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the changeApptThemes = null; 

**Back to App Settings Table View**

viewWillAppear of the App Settings
selecteTheme in the App Settings = Peacock
Navigation Bar still default (tab bar and background normal). 

**Go To Timeline Table View**

viewWillAppear of the Timeline
selectedTheme in the viewWillAppear = null; 
Navigation Bar changed appropriately. 

**Go to App Settings**

viewWillAppear of the App Settings
selecteTheme in the viewWillAppear = Peacock

**Segue to Theme Collection:**

viewDidLoad of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the viewDidLoad = null;

viewWillAppear of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the viewWillAppear = null

changeAppThemes of the Theme Collection
selectedTheme in the changeAppThemes = null; 
Navigation bar does not equal transparent bar like it should.
```

If you read through the logs, there's some strange behaviour where the `selectedThemes` is null through the `segues`, etc, therefore indicating that it's not loading from the `NSUserDefaults`

I need to fix the following problems:

1) When a user taps a `cell` in the `Themes Collection`, change the `UINavigationBar` as well as the `Tab Bar` and `Background` (it makes no sense to me why the `tab bar` and `background` change but the `nav bar` doesn't, in the same if statement).

2) Fix the scenarios above where in many cases, `self.selectedThemes` is `null`, even though it should be loaded from the `NSUserDefaults`

I'm not using any prepareForSegue code from the App Setting to the Theme Collections.

I have also tried to set up the `changeAppThemes` method in the `Timeline` and `App Settings` and call that from the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` in the `App Settings`, `Timeline` and `Collection Views`, with the same results.

Everything is built in `Storyboard`. The `Timeline` and `App settings` are embedded in a `navigation controller`.

I'm sorry this is long, but its a seriously complicated issue that I just really need to understand and get some assistance on, so any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue with the following code:

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueyNav.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```